# unable to start FOP in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, apache-fop, invocationtargetexception

Getting the following error while building Job in Jenkins:

Details

```
Mode       LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
----       -------------     ------ --------      
6/28/2016   3:40 PM            Temp
```

Jenkins Error log building application: "InvocationTargetException"

```
  Processing main file...
  Unable to start FOP:
   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.startFOPWithDynamicClasspath(Main.java:133)
   at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.main(Main.java:207)
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlgraphics/image/loader/ImageContext
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.fop.cli.CommandLineOptions.<init>(CommandLineOptions.java:121)
   at org.apache.fop.cli.Main.startFOP(Main.java:157)
   ... 6 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageContext
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   ... 19 more
  fatal error: DocBook transformation failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Please include xmlgraphics-commons-1.3.jar in your maven dependency.

   ```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
   ```